# What would be the best way for me to collect postcodes in store?

Tags: android, database

I am looking for a way for our customers to leave their postcode with us during a sale rush. Typically, we have a big sale every two months, and that brings in a lot of foot traffic.

In an effort to be more effective with out traditional marketing, we want to see what areas of this state bring in the most people, by using the post code as an indicator.

Currently, our staff hand write the 6 digit number down when a customer pays at the checkout, and then have it batch processed by two interns. This is time-consuming and it's not teaching our interns anything useful.

Ideally, I'd like an android app (or to be able to create one, tho I am not a programmer) that simply displays a key pad on a tablet, that would be placed next to the credit card machine. creating a new line with the number in a file, that I can later download.

It doesn't have to connect to the net, I'd be more than happy to retrieve the files from the device every so often

Having looked at a few DB apps on the google play store, I wasn't able to find one that worked well or displayed information in a way I'd be happy with.

Some additional information.

We have a POS system, but it's closed source, and frankly scammy. We are not able to edit, or create a customer profile on the fly, or add one later. The software and the developer house won't allow that with out an unreasonable charge for a new version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database apps have you already checked and found unsatisfying? Not that we recommend you just those :) Also, while waiting for answers, be welcome to take a look at [my list of DB apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_databases) – and if you find a match, please [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Good luck meanwhile!